# Create and manage a custon table in an extension: How to

Tags: extension

In my extension (it's the first one I'm writing) I have the need to create a new DB table and to manage it (insert, update, delete records).
How can I do it?
Thanks
Marcello

Answer (score 3):

Check this section on the wiki: https://wiki.civicrm.org/confluence/display/CRMDOC/Create+a+Module+Extension#CreateaModuleExtension-Addadatabaseupgrader/Installer/uninstaller
You will need to add an upgrader to your extension, and from that upgrader you can manage your database file installs. Also, you might want to add a DAO class?

Comment: Thank's ErickH, I had already read that section and I'm able to create/destroy my table on the DB and I made some web forms.
My problem Is now how to create: 1) a table element list  page with buttons Add, Modify ... 2) an edit form. There are some examples or maybe a some code page I can use to start?

Comment: Can I avoid to create a DAO class?

Comment: You certainly can, but it might make life easier if you do. It depends on what you want to do with your table. If I want to use it in a form and page etc. having a DAO actually helps me.